# Turn Ringer Silent based on Location Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I have prepared the app and I am stuck at adding the code to turn the ringer silent. When I press the button a notification is sent but I want to turn the ringer volume to 0. This is my code. ALSO I AM CONFUSED WHERE TO PUT THE CODE.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol AddViewControllerDelegate {
    func addViewController(controller: AddViewController, didAddCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, identifier: String, note: String, eventType: EventType)
}

class AddViewController: UITableViewController {


@IBOutlet var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var zoomButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var eventTypeSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var radiusTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var noteTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var delegate: AddViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addButton, zoomButton]
    addButton.isEnabled = false
}

@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    addButton.isEnabled = !radiusTextField.text!.isEmpty && !noteTextField.text!.isEmpty
}

@IBAction func onCancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction private func onAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
    let coordinate = mapView.centerCoordinate
    let radius = Double(radiusTextField.text!) ?? 0
    let identifier = NSUUID().uuidString
    let note = noteTextField.text
    let eventType: EventType = (eventTypeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? .onEntry : .onExit
    delegate?.addViewController(controller: self, didAddCoordinate: coordinate, radius: radius, identifier: identifier, note: note!, eventType: eventType)
}

@IBAction private func onZoomToCurrentLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    mapView.zoomToUserLocation()
}
}
```

Comment: An app can't change the ringer volume.  Due to sandboxing you are prevented from modifying the environment outside your own app.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to turn ringer silent from the app. The app always bounds to it's environment